# Android Studio unable to display version number on app

Tags: android

I am trying to add my app version to the app. Below is my code

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="@color/white">
 <PreferenceCategory android:title="Version">
    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="@string/version"
        />
</PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

**Fragment**

```
import com.example.thumbsol.accuratesurvey.BuildConfig;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    String verName = BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME;
    int verCode = BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE;
    // Load the preferences from an XML resource
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    version = (EditTextPreference)findPreference(getString(R.string.version));
    version.setText(verName);
}
```

**GUI**

[image]

**Update 1**

Below is my gradle

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.thumbsol.accuratesurvey"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 33
    versionCode 3
    versionName "3.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

}
```

It doesn't show any version name. Although I have debugged the code and checked it.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What color is the text?

Comment: @JakeB default is black

Comment: Can you paste the BuildConfig import statement from the top of the class

Comment: @JakeB here it is `import com.example.thumbsol.accuratesurvey.BuildConfig;`

Comment: And that's your application's package name?

Comment: @JakeB yes exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you had set version name to the EditTextPreference! but EditTextPreference is extend DialogPreference, you can click the blank area，a dialog would be shown and the version name you got had been set in the EditText!

So what you want is only add the version name to the Settings! you can change EditTextPreference to the normal Preference:

```
<PreferenceCategory android:title="Version">
    <Preference
        android:key="@string/version" />
</PreferenceCategory>
```

then in your activity:

```
Preference version = (Preference)findPreference(getString(R.string.version));
version.setTitle("Version Name");
version.setSummary(verName);
```

Hope this can help you!

Answer (score 2):

In order to use `BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME` you need to set it inside your applications `build.gradle` file.

```
android {
   ...
   defaultConfig {
      ...
      versionName "1.1.0"
      versionCode 11
   }
```

Comment: It's already there..

Answer (score 1):

When I need to know the version of my app, I use the package manager:

```
    PackageInfo myPackageInfo = null;

    try {
        myPackageInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), 0);
        String verName = myPackageInfo.versionName;
        int verCode = myPackageInfo.versionCode;
    } 
    catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this to read android version and app name.

```
 private String versionName,appVersion;

 versionName = BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME;
 appVersion = versionName.substring(0, 5).trim();
 Log.i("versionName:", versionName);
 Log.i("Version Name :", appVersion);
```

Comment: getting `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=5` at `appVersion = versionName.substring(0, 5).trim();` on `substring` part

Comment: use appVersion = versionName.toString;

Comment: getting `I/versionName:: 3.0` and `I/Version Name :: 3.0`

Comment: that is for version, try for app name  AppName =  context.getString(R.string.app_name);

Comment: `I/App Name :: Wrfnan Mobile Booking`

Comment: I am still unable to show app version on my app

Answer (score 0):

Example usage available.

**SettingsActivity.java -> Your.**

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
    
    public static final String TAG = "caveman";
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);
    
        Preference pref = findPreference( "developer" );
        pref.setSummary("Marathon Apps");
    
        Preference pref1 = findPreference( "version" );
        try {
            pref1.setSummary(appVersion());
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    
        LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout)findViewById(android.R.id.list).getParent().getParent().getParent();
        Toolbar bar = (Toolbar) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tool_bar, root, false);
        root.addView(bar, 0); // insert at top
        bar.setTitle("Prism");
        bar.setSubtitle("Settings");
        bar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
    
    public String appVersion() throws PackageManager.NameNotFoundException {
        PackageInfo pInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
        String version = pInfo.versionName;
        return version;
    }
```

**pref_settings.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<PreferenceCategory
android:title="About">
<PreferenceScreen
    android:title="Developer"
    android:key="developer"
    android:summary="Marathon Apps">
</PreferenceScreen>

<PreferenceScreen
    android:title="Version"
    android:key="version"
    android:summary="1.0">
</PreferenceScreen>
</PreferenceCategory>


</PreferenceScreen>
```